# how to put dreamlinux on usb drive and install it on computer

Tags: linux, usb

I want to put dreamlinux on my old laptop.  The cd drive on that laptop does not work.  So I want it to boot from a usb stick.

what should I put on the USB stick so it will boot dream linux from it?

I have downloaded the dreamlinux iso. should i just put the iso on the usb drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamlinux provides a [tutorial](http://www.dreamlinux.com.br/tutorials/3.0/usb-install/usb-install.html) on installing to a pen drive.

Since your drive does not work, you can use the ISO with a virtual machine to boot it live within your current environment, then use Pen-DLI to put it on your USB. You can use [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) to create the virtual machine.